# How does superfluid dark matter keep stars orbiting at high speeds in galaxies?

Tags: galaxy, gravity, dark-matter

According to [A paper on Ultra-Light Dark Matter](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.03254), Superfluid dark matter is a kind of Bose-Einstein condensate. But how does it help stars keep their high or  velocities in galaxies. Can somebody explain this .Section 4.2.2  Superfluid Dynamics is the relevant section, I think

Comment: Information necessary to understand your question belong into the question, not into the comments.

Comment: Are you wondering why the DM-baryon interaction term (equation 195) does not slow stars?

Comment: @Sten Yes why doesn't it slow stars?

Answer (score -1):

The theory is wrong, for multiple reasons.

## Why the theory is wrong:

We need a complete revision of what a Bose-Einstein condensate actually is.

A Bose-Einstein condensate is basically a dilute gas of atoms which are cooled down to near absolute zero. As the temperature approaches absolute zero, the atoms coalesce into one (relatively) giant "superatom". Basically, thousands of atoms coalesce and behave like one single atom, that is they represent a single matter-wave function.

Dark matter, in contrast defies all of the properties of a true BEC. Modern theories suggest that dark matter's particles (if they do exist), the axions, [do not interact with even themselves](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.sciencenews.org/article/dark-matter-isnt-interacting-itself-after-all&ved=2ahUKEwiLn-XOqY7_AhUyTWwGHV-tDmM4ChAWegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw2IzybWev6wth_0LJCJVie4). BEC, on the other hand, have literal particles interact with each other to form a single matter-wave function. Dark matter also cannot behave like a superfluid. We already have made Superfluid helium on earth, and we know that despite zero viscosity, [superfluids are still fluids and obey Bernoulli's principle.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/126286/344106) Meaning that despite zero viscosity, [even superfluids exert viscous drag on an object passing through it.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.sciencenews.org/article/dark-matter-isnt-interacting-itself-after-all&ved=2ahUKEwiLn-XOqY7_AhUyTWwGHV-) Meaning that if the universe was filled with superfluid dark matter, according to the theory, the Universe would have actually collapsed into a black hole or its original state, a infinitesimally small singularity! Because stull being fluids, superfluids would exert viscous drag on the atoms of matter and thus lose speed and collapse back into a black hole.

I am afraid that the theory of a BEC or superfluid dark matter is much more inaccurate than the theory that the universe is a simulation and black holes are glitches in space-time, which is also inaccurate.

Tl;dr: I am afraid that the theory is wrong.

So, in short that theory does not explain how dark matter can keep stars and galaxies moving at high velocity.

Comment: Why the downvote? If there is anything wrong in this answer, please let me know, and I will correct it.

Comment: Nothing wrong I downvoted accidentally while writing a response .Your link to evidence for non self  interacting dark matter was was interesting.

Comment: Axions are a useful DM candidate because they can explain the Strong CP problem   "Strong CP problem - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_CP_problem and this https://www.newscientist.com/article/2369958-weird-dark-matter-waves-seem-to-warp-the-light-from-distant-galaxies/

Comment: While I don't know much about the model, here are some issues I'm seeing with the answer: (1) While superfluidity requires self-interactions, Bose-Einstein condensation does not. (2) Dark matter self-interactions are not ruled out anyway, only constrained to certain degrees in many regimes. (3) Axions are only one of many dark matter candidates. (4) Viscous drag isn't relevant to expansion, as that doesn't involve shearing motion. (5) Your link doesn't support the claim that superfluids exert viscous drag.

Comment: I should point out that the article you link (for which the associated research article is [1708.04245](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04245)) concerns [self-interacting dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-interacting_dark_matter), which has a very different phenomenology from superfluid dark matter. Also, it doesn't rule out self-interacting dark matter; it only counters previous claims that the system they are studying shows evidence for self-interacting dark matter.